# HTML5 game file parsing

Tags: file, html, parsing

I'm currently working on a game in html5, using the canvas element and I've currently got the webpage on my local hard drive in a folder, now what I am trying to do is to be able for my website to read a XML file or even a text file's contents that is within a sub directory of the game folder. The reason why I am doing this is for level creation and custom tile creation and to hold the data necessary for sprites and things of that nature, so far I have found information on loading XML data through a server but NOT within the same directory as the webpage I am working on. I need to be able to read this data only through the files that are local to the websites directory.

Comment: You mean those XML files shouldn't be viewed by users directly?

Comment: they really aren't being viewed by the user as much as the data is just being read off of them, the game will allow people to be able to create their own level data and things of that nature, the game will probally eventually be put as a website but for now i'm leaving it as a local website stored on the hard drive.

Comment: I am too late to reply but want to share an example
https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/hopeofabug
In this game i have used files to store users information like id, score and level for. Those files are not public to the users but my system can read it. I didn't minify the JS, you can have a look into it. If you want more assistance, i can give you the source chunks which you required.
By the way, i appreciate your approach. Its really handy to use files instead of DB when you are thinking like a gamer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load files locally using Javascipt because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You should set up a local test server on your computer.

If your planning on developing server-side using PHP you could use [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). Just google 'running php locally on my machine'.

I personally use Python on Google App Engine because it's free (for small projects) and I can actually test my web-apps online or locally.